# Matching Pursuit Algorithm using Gabor Dictionary in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wavelet

I'm looking for a Matlab function which would decompose a signal using Matching Pursuit (MP) algorithm composed of Gabor atoms.

I'm fairly new to adaptive signal processing. I have downloaded Wavelab but it doesn't implement MP algorithm using Gabor dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Matching Pursuit ToolKit](http://mptk.irisa.fr/) has a Matlab interface.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did install the MPToolKit before posting the question but I was unable to get it to work. I couldn't find the directory where the toolkit was installed (for MacOSX) and nor could I find any user documents. Fortunately today I was able find the documents and get it to work! The documents are located here: https://gforge.inria.fr/docman/?group_id=36#

Also, it's by default installed into "/usr/local/mptk" folder for MacOSX. 

Thanks again for your help!